# How to get height of an id-based element div with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When hovering an element a `div` will be shown. I have a couple of this elements. So each `div` has an unique `id`and each it's own height. To align the `div`-class next to the cursor I need to know its individual height.

Here is an extraction of what I got (please note the lines that I have marked with ****):

```
$('.rsshover').mouseleave(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace("did_", "");
    $("#pre_"+id).hide();
});    

// cache the selector
var follower = $(".preview");
var IDHeight = ****???****
var xp = 0, yp = 0;
var loop = setInterval(function(){
    xp += (mouseX + 15 - xp) / 12;
    yp += (mouseY - ****IDHeight**** - yp) / 12;
    follower.css({left:xp, top:yp});
}, 0);
```

So what I would like to archieve can be seen in that [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d278yu9h/3/) and when entering a value for a specific height like `yp += (mouseY - 200 - yp) / 12;`.

The `a`elements are placed on the bottom of the page. So the hidden `div`s need to grow upwards what means that the starting reference-point of the `div` should be the left-bottom-edge and instead building it up downwards it needs to grow upwards.

So I have no clue how to solve this. Would appreciate if there is someone who could help me out. Thanks in advance.

Here is what it should look like and what I want to achieve. I needed to enter two different heights manually by hand in that line `yp += (mouseY - **HEIGHTVALUE** - yp) / 12;`

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Comment: _initialise the height_ of newly created div, right? The original elements will have some height of their own, right?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using jquery, you can get height of any div by `$('#someid').height();`

Comment: the problem is more that I don't know how to initialise the height because I have actually no mouseover etc. function where I check for the id.

Comment: You have multiple elements with some id. When you hover over any of the element, you create a new *div*, whose height you want to maintain same as the original element's height. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n3wozf2b/ Check if you want to achieve something like this? `<p>` is causing some overflow, which can be overridden using CSS.

Comment: Sorry, I should give more information what I would like to achieve. Thats not what I want. I will give further information in my question.

Comment: I've added two screenshots. Please have a look at the cursor and from where the div is placed.

Answer (score 0):

The below example provides the functionality you seek.

```js
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0, limitX = 320, limitY = 15;
$('.alink').mousemove(function(e){
   var id = $(this).attr('id').replace("id_", "");    
    // get the current hidden div selector
    var follower = $("#div_to_id_"+id);
    follower.show();
    // change 12 to alter damping higher is slower
    follower.animate({
    left: e.pageX,
    top: e.pageY-(follower.height()+30),
    height: "auto"
  }, 10, function() {    
  });   
});
$('.alink').mouseleave(function() {
        $(".hiddendivs").hide(); 
});
```

```css
a {
    display: inline-block;
    width:320px;
    height:15px;   
    position:relative;
    margin-top: 150px;
    background-color: red;
}

.hiddendivs {
  background: green;
 color: #fff;
  width: 310px;
  padding: 15px; 
  position:fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="alink" id="id_1">
  <div class="hiddendivs" id="div_to_id_1"> 
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod temp...</p>
  </div>
</a>
          
<a href="#" class="alink" id="id_2">
  <div class="hiddendivs" id="div_to_id_2"> 
    <p>some other content...</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

Updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d278yu9h/6/)